# Compile a gpsd client in C++

Tags: c++, linux, gpsd

I'm attempting to compile a client program of gpsd using the following command:

```
g++ gpsClient.cpp -o gpsClient $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libgps)
```

The source code begins like that

```
#include <libgpsmm>
```

The error is the following:

```
Package libgpsmm was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

Comment: Do you have other packages named `*gps*` in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`? Try them instead of `libgpsmm`. Failing that, try to install one or more packages named `libgps*` or `gpsd*` and repeat.

Comment: I don't have any packages named *gps* in /usr/lib/pkgconfig. I've installed the gpsd deamon with the following command: sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients

Comment: @vudu Don't check for `gps`, check for `*gps*`. You can also run `pkg-config --list-all` to get a list of all libraries. You can search for `*gps*` by piping the output to `grep`: `pkg-config --list-all | grep -i *gps*`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I run `pkg-config --list-all` and I´ve found a `libgps` package, then now it works. Also, the calling is `#include <libgpsmm.h>` not `#include <libgpsmm>`.

Answer (score 3):

Answering in case someone else encounters this issue.

The proper header file to include is, as suggested in the comments:

```
#include <libgpsmm.h>
```

pkg-config should then be able to find the proper search path, assuming *gpsd* (and/or depending on the OS, *libgps-dev* or variants thereof) is installed.

There's a good gist on github I use as a base for interacting with gpsd clients in C++ here: [example c++ gpsd program using libgpsmm](https://gist.github.com/ncoder-1/8313815ac387e6757f751dc8960f03d7)

It even has an example compile command (adapt to clang or other if needed):

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -pedantic $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libgps) gpsd-example.cpp -o gpsd-example
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data from `gpsd`, make sure you have installed `libgps-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libgps-dev
```

And in case you want to use it in CMakeLists, `gps`- and `m`-linker flags should be linked to the target:

```
set(GPS_FLAGS m gps)
#
# other components  
# 
add_executable([PROJECT_NAME] ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries([PROJECT_NAME] ${GPS_FLAGS})
```